# Dual Screen Application using Zinc

Tags: actionscript, mdm-zinc

I am trying to decide what is going to be the best option to use for this scenario, Zinc or Adobe Air.

I have a client who needs a backend touchscreen panel with a few buttons which, when pressed on will start a video on a dual screen setup on the other monitor.

Using Zinc, will I be able to create two Exe files, one exe to host the backend "control panel" and the other exe to host the video player where the video will be played and will they be able to talk to one another. So if I press stop in the control panel, the video needs to stop in the other exe.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe AIR has multi-monitor support using the class [flash.display.Screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/display/Screen.html).

The Screen class allows you to detect screens and their visible boundaries.  You can use this information to build your views in AIR.  You can have one of your views on the 'backend' dispatch events, which would then be handled by your client.  A co-worker of mine did a project almost identical to this for a museum kiosk (touchscreen on bottom, video window on top).

Take a look at [this guy's blog post](http://www.joristimmerman.be/wordpress/2009/03/03/screenmanager-expand-your-air-application/) for some insight on how to use the Screen class to manage NativeWindows in AIR.